# How do you order by negative and positive numbers DB2 Sql Syntax

Tags: sql, db2

When I run the following Sql I get the following results DB2 SQL :

```
    Select * from LOTOIL1 where lotkey = 'B20130806'
    order by OIPRI ASC
```

The results :

[image]

I am ordering on OIPRI and would like to get the results  :

```
-3
-1
0
3
```

What do I need to do to get the results?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the datatype of `OIPRI`?

Comment: I dare to bet that it is a non-numeric datatype because it sorts alphabetically.

Comment: @MartinSmith Its a Char.

Comment: So why are you storing integers in a character column? If you fix the datatype it will be stored more efficiently, you won't get invalid non numeric values and it will sort correctly. is there some trailing text? Wondering why it shows ellipsis in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
order by OIPRI * 1 ASC
```

to force `integer` conversion.

But actually you should change your data type to a numeric type.

Comment: I would use `CAST(OIPRI AS INTEGER)` instead... some (older) versions of DB2 don't support implicit casting.